# How to Repeat a sheet entry that is connected internally to a BUS

Tags: altium

In Altium Schematic Design, I have a circuit (CER1) in a sheet, and I use a BUS to connect multiple channels.
In the parent schematic, I created a sheet symbol from the CER1 sheet. And since I needed to use CER1 twice I used the REPEAT function to repeat the block, and the entries. Everything is working well except the sheet entry that has a bus connected to it internally. it is giving an error "Bus Range syntax error"
How should I repeat this Bus?
[image: CER1]

[image: Repeated Block]

Comment: Have you asked this question on one of the many Altium support sites before asking here?

Comment: For some reason, the Altium forum is unavailable!

Comment: In case nobody answers (I don't use altium) there are other support sites. Altium discord is one of them. I believe it's quite busy.